# what is reason that `.toString()` method throw an exception when value is null while Convert`.ToString()` automatic handle null value

Tags: c#, methods

What is reason that `.ToString()` method throw an exception when value is null while `Convert.ToString()` automatic handle null value in C#.

Comment: i think its implemention of `Convert.ToString()`. it will first check for null value. then will call `ToString`.

Answer (score 9):

`Object.ToString()` is an *instance method* called on an *instance* of `Object` class. If that instance is a null reference then you are calling a method of an instance that doesn't exist (isn't instantiated, doesn't reference anything). Calling any method on a reference which references `null` would yield a null reference exception.

On the other hand, `Convert.ToString(someObject)` is a *static method* of the `Convert` class which accepts an instance `someObject` and converts it to string. In this case *someObject* is a parameter to a method so it can be null.

Answer (score 3):

It is not correct to say that `ToString()` throws an exception when it is invoked on a `null` object, because any method invoked on a `null` object throws an exception. CLR checks the object for `null` *before* it gets to decide on what object to call `ToString`, sees `null`, and throws the exception.

Convert.ToString(), on the other hand, is invoked statically, so it does not throw right away. Now the method itself, not the CLR, gets a chance to check the object for `null`, and return whatever it is to return in this situation.

C# lets you have almost the same effect with the `?.` operator: if you do this

```
string s = obj?.ToString();
```

`s` would be `null` and no exception would be thrown when `obj` is `null`.